# DropDownList, getting DataValueField returned in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have a drop down list that pulls data from a database to show some of its options:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PK_Task" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="dropDownList">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">General Support</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Vacation</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Sick Leave</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Something Else</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_Task], [Name] FROM [Task] WHERE ([PointPerson] LIKE '%' + @PointPerson + '%') AND [Status] NOT LIKE 'Done'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="PointPerson" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As you can see, I only display the [Name] column:

```
DataTextField="Name"
```

But I am also getting the primary key SELECT [PK_Task], [Name] FROM:

```
DataValueField="PK_Task"
```

How do I get access to this primary key based on user selection. If a user selects a specific 'name' from the drop down menu, what C# can I use to get the corresponding primary key returned to me so I can save it in a variable?

The closest I have gotten is this, but all it does is return the string "PK_Task":

```
String taskID = DropDownList3.DataValueField;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640676/asp-net-datavaluefield-in-dropdownlist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedValue` property:

```
// to set
DropDownList3.SelectedValue = "1";

// to read
string value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
String taskID = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

any way you can use
either

```
dropdown3.selectedvalue
```

or

```
dropdown3.selecteditem.value
```

Comment: since you have use dropdown.datavaluefield, so its returning you the name of field you bind.