# How to get DataValueField from dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get data from dropdownlist selected item with sql server.But it's don't working.

My asp.net desing codes:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drp_SiparisYazan" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSiparisYazan" DataTextField="ACIKLAMA" DataValueField="KOD"></asp:DropDownList>       
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceSiparisYazan" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:.. %>' SelectCommand="SELECT  ...'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I putting valuefield from sqlserver.After It is returning null value in selecteditem.Value.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdSave = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con);
    cmdSave.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siparisyazan", drp_SiparisYazan.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you explain a bit more? Is the populating of the dropdownlist working?

Comment: Yes working dropdownlist and it taking data in dropdownlist.But I dont getting selecteditem value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DropDownList, getting DataValueField returned in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348678/dropdownlist-getting-datavaluefield-returned-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still a null value.I want to getting KOD in value.

Comment: @EmreAslan i found your issue, checkout the second update on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greetings you can use

```
string value = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
```

and insert the `value` to your database.

**Update:**

Bind your SqlDataSource's SelectCommand in your code behind in your page_load:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  SqlDataSourceSiparisYazan.SelectCommand = "Your Query";
  //Make Sure your query is right, trace it with breakpoint
}
```

And Empty its SelectCommand in your .aspx file:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceSiparisYazan" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPMMASTER_PGCS %>' SelectCommand=""></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then try to get the SelectedValue.

**Second Update:**
I looked at your `Dropdownlist` again you didn't bind the `KOD` to `DataValueField` (as if its the value?) And you didn't bind the `Its Name`(Whatever it is) to `DataTextField` and you expect magically get the value?

Edit your `DropdownList` Like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceSiparisYazan" DataTextField="Field of the Name to be shown" DataValueField="KOD" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CPMMASTER_PGCS %>' SelectCommand="SELECT KOD,ACIKLAMA FROM REFKRT ...'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: This is identical to .SelectedItem.Value, he is already using that.

Comment: @Esko found the issue, he didn't bind the DataValueField on Dropdownlist, using SQLDataSource you need to bind the field otherwise it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the selected value of dropdownlist in code behind by using 
"drp_SiparisYazan.SelectedValue"

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Text"></asp:DropDownList>
```

(object have ID, Text,...)

and bind List to ddl:`ddl.DataSource = list<object>`
get value use: `ddl.SelectedValue`